# PHP MySQL Database backend

Tags: php, sql, database

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this line?

```
VALUES('$_POST[POS]','$_POST[GP]','$_POST[Goals]','$_POST[Assists]','$_POST[Points]','$_POST[Polarity]','$_POST[PPG]','$_POST[SHG]','$_POST[PIM]','$_POST[Hits]','$_POST[Shots]','$_POST[Shots %]')";
```

It's in context with:

```
<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","ernie","gomes");
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("ernie", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO statplayer (POS, GP, Goals, Assists, Points, Polarity, PPG, SHG, PIM, Hits, Shots, Shot %)
VALUES('$_POST[POS]','$_POST[GP]','$_POST[Goals]','$_POST[Assists]','$_POST[Points]','$_POST[Polarity]','$_POST[PPG]','$_POST[SHG]','$_POST[PIM]','$_POST[Hits]','$_POST[Shots]','$_POST[Shots %]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
 echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
 ?>
```

Comment: What error do you get? Also, look up SQL Injection.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ']' in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\ernie\add\statplayer.php on line 20

Comment: the place it takes place in is here: http://www.u4ik.us/ernie/add     username is ernie pass is gomes and its only on the second form. It's identical to the first, which works, but different table.

Comment: What Blair said, please for the love of god look it up or you may feel the wraith of lulzsec someday.

Comment: @zerkms: Are you sure the `$_POST[Shots %]` is OK?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I'm sure that OP used **perfectly valid** syntax. For complex array keys you could use `{...}` http://ideone.com/sLxdS More details is in php manual in working with strings section

Comment: @zerkms: Yeah, OK. Braces are a nice thing, too, but no need to clutter up the code if the current form is correct.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: you mentioned "complex" keys and I just answered how to deal with them ;-)

Comment: Hey wait a minute: [Error](http://ideone.com/lxKwT)! Isn't that exactly like the OP's `$_POST[Shots %]`?

Comment: Also, if the username and password listed in your `mysql_connect` are the *real* values, you should change them.  If you haven't dealt with SQL Injection issues, I'm willing to bet that you haven't  locked down the database user privileges either.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments to the question have been suggesting, it seems to be due to the space in `Shots %`. This needs to be quoted, in both SQL and PHP. Your error is a PHP error, but I think you'll get an SQL error once you fix it.

See below for how to put quotes around that name.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO statplayer (POS, GP, Goals, Assists, Points, Polarity, PPG, SHG, PIM, Hits, Shots, `Shot %`)
VALUES('$_POST[POS]','$_POST[GP]','$_POST[Goals]','$_POST[Assists]','$_POST[Points]','$_POST[Polarity]','$_POST[PPG]','$_POST[SHG]','$_POST[PIM]','$_POST[Hits]','$_POST[Shots]','."$_POST['Shots %']."')";
```

or

```
$sql="INSERT INTO statplayer (POS, GP, Goals, Assists, Points, Polarity, PPG, SHG, PIM, Hits, Shots, `Shot %`)
VALUES('$_POST[POS]','$_POST[GP]','$_POST[Goals]','$_POST[Assists]','$_POST[Points]','$_POST[Polarity]','$_POST[PPG]','$_POST[SHG]','$_POST[PIM]','$_POST[Hits]','$_POST[Shots]','{$_POST['Shots %']}')";
```

But **please** read about [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20sql%20injection) and how to prevent it. Your code is **completely** vulnerable.

Comment: This still didn't work, Blair. I see the loopholes of using your own document to feed the php inserts. It's just that I whipped this up and have no interest at the moment of fixing it. Likely will do that tomorrow.

Comment: IMO the braces are harder to understand at first for new learners. I'll put it as an option as well though to keep you happy :)

Comment: Actually, why can't we use Bash-type braces, like `${Arr['key']}`? That'd be fairly easy to parse, because it'd use the uniform `${...}` syntax to refer to a variable...

Comment: Blair's second method did the trick Thanks. I'm going to add security tomorrow.

Comment: Also read http://www.talkphp.com/general/1062-securing-your-mysql-queries-sprintf.html

Comment: Good to know. Don't forget to mark the question as answered, and also, **make sure** that you fix your SQL injection issues before you use the page (putting the page on the internet counts as using the page). Your link in your comment allows the world to access your whole database. Please fix it :)

Comment: If only I could find the "mark as answered" button. Yes, sad. Very sad.

Comment: There is a gray-outlined checkmark under the downvote button at the top left of Blair's question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are many problems with your code, but we all have to start somewhere. At the top of your script, put the following to turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

You should do this for every file you have in order to produce better code. To answer your question, the reason it's failing is because you need to put curly braces around your array variables, like this:

```
$string = "Some text with a {$array['var']} variable";
```

Also, notice that 'var' has quotes around it. You cannot do $array[var] (without quoting 'var' or else you're going to get a notice that var has not been defined. Also, it is not recommended to use spaces or characters like '%' in your variable names. I have therefore changed it in the example below to 'ShotPercent' instead.

As many other people have mentioned, your script is vulnerable to SQL injection, so I would **highly recommend you ditch the mysql_* functions completely**. They are outdated. Instead, use PDO. Something like this should work:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'ernie';
$user = 'ernie';
$pass = 'gomes';

try {
    $dbh = new LoggedPDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("DB connection error: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$sql="INSERT INTO statplayer (POS, GP, Goals, Assists, Points, Polarity, PPG, SHG, PIM, Hits, Shots, ShotPercent)
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

try {
    $sth->execute(array($_POST['POS'], $_POST['GP'], $_POST['Goals'], $_POST['Assists'], $_POST['Points'], $_POST['Polarity'], $_POST['PPG'] , $_POST['SHG'], $_POST['PIM'], $_POST['Hits'], $_POST['Shots'],$_POST['ShotPercent']));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die(echo $e->getMessage());
}

echo $sth->rowCount() .' record(s) added';
```